# Parallel computation. NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, task

I'm making my first steps in parallel programming. I rewrote CalculateSlots to CalculateSlotsAsync. It seams to work fine (3 times faster).

My questions are: Is it written correctly?
Do I need to use the newest async awayt pattern and if yes, how?

```
private void CalculateSlots(bool isCalculateAllSlots)
{
    foreach (IndicatorSlot indicatorSlot in strategy.Slot)
    {
        if (isCalculateAllSlots || !indicatorSlot.IsCalculated)
            CalculateStrategySlot(indicatorSlot.SlotNumber);
    }
}

private void CalculateSlotsAsync(bool isCalculateAllSlots)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (IIndicatorSlot indicatorSlot in strategy.Slot)
    {
        if (isCalculateAllSlots || !indicatorSlot.IsCalculated)
        {
            IIndicatorSlot slot = indicatorSlot;
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CalculateStrategySlot(slot.SlotNumber));
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Test on i7-3630QM @2.40Gh

```
// Executed for 96 sec. 
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    CalculateSlots(true);

// Executed for 34 sec. 
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    CalculateSlotsAsync(true);
```

Comment: Code review is not the purpose of SO. Code looks OK but could be streamlined with (P)Linq and/or Parallel.ForEach().

Comment: I'm using SO from two years and still cannot understand what exactly is it purpose. I really afraid to ask something here or especially to answer. Reading here asking in other place...

Comment: @MiroslavPopov: I assume Henk meant that the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site might be more appropriate for these kinds of questions. But don't be afraid of asking questions; the worst that can happen is that it will get closed without receiving any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For data-parallel operations, you can often simplify your implementation by using PLINQ:

```
strategy.Slot.AsParallel()
             .Where(slot => isCalculateAllSlots || !indicatorSlot.IsCalculated)
             .ForAll(slot => CalculateStrategySlot(slot.SlotNumber));
```

However, in your case, each item takes a relatively long time to compute, so I would recommend leaving them as tasks but marking them as [`LongRunning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) (which typically has the effect of executing them on a dedicated thread, rather than the thread pool).

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CalculateStrategySlot(slot.SlotNumber),
                                  TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

**Reply**: `Task.WaitAll` causes the calling thread – in your case, the UI thread – to block until all specified tasks have completed. (The behaviour is similar for the PLINQ `ForAll`.)

In order for your UI to remain responsive, you need to switch from a blocking approach to an asynchronous one. For example, suppose you have:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
UpdateUI(strategy.Slot);    // must be called on UI thread
```

You can replace this with:

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), completedTasks =>
{
    // callback on UI thread
    UpdateUI(strategy.Slot);
},
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskContinuationOptions.None,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

In practice, you'll also need to learn how to use `CancellationToken` to allow the user to discard the operation before it completes.

Comment: Thank you @Douglas! Tested AsParalle() code. Much cleaner than mine. It seams I'm missing something. If it's parallel, why it blocks my UI for the time of full calculation?

Comment: +1 Thank you @Douglas. Shame I cannot vote with +5 for such constructive answer. A user must be able rate a one line hint and an answer with several examples properly.

Comment: You're welcome :-) The important thing for me is that your query got properly resolved.